# Instantiating MapBox before inflating the fragment layout cause Exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm following MabBox tutorial at https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-navigation-sdk/ to make a simple navigation fragment that use the basics elements of it.

I already know that MapBox require to instantiate before inflating the View because I made it before on another Fragment to test it out where the fragment is part of a TabLayout component, however, in this one, there's only one Activity that loads the Fragment where I use the SDK and in this case it throws the same error that I fixed previously because I put it afterinflating the layout.

The errore that appears is this one:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.parkingclientapplication, PID: 14257
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.parkingclientapplication/com.example.parkingclientapplication.activities.MapDirectionActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.parkingclientapplication.activities.MapDirectionActivity.onCreate(MapDirectionActivity.kt:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.exceptions.MapboxConfigurationException: 
    Using MapView requires calling Mapbox.getInstance(Context context, String accessToken) before inflating or creating the view. The access token parameter is required when using a Mapbox service.
    Please see https://www.mapbox.com/help/create-api-access-token/ to learn how to create one.
    More information in this guide https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-android-sdk/#access-tokens.
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox.validateMapbox(Mapbox.java:165)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox.getAccessToken(Mapbox.java:77)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.storage.FileSource.<init>(FileSource.java:234)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.storage.FileSource.getInstance(FileSource.java:68)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.renderer.MapRenderer.<init>(MapRenderer.java:34)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.renderer.glsurfaceview.GLSurfaceViewMapRenderer.<init>(GLSurfaceViewMapRenderer.java:33)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$5.<init>(MapView.java:294)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.initialiseDrawingSurface(MapView.java:294)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.initialize(MapView.java:137)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:100)
            ... 25 more
```

The code for the Activity is:

```
class MapDirectionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_direction)

        supportFragmentManager.inTransaction {
            add(R.id.form_clientNavMenu, MapDirectionFragment())
        }
        //Logout action on custom toolbar layout
        logout.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the onCreateView method of the Fragment is:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        Mapbox.getInstance(context!!, getString(R.string.access_token))
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_direction, container, false)

        mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapView)
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mapView.getMapAsync(this)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view
}
```

I only wrote onCreateView method because I think the error could be in there instead on the rest of the code which is the same as in the link, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The exception states: 
`Caused by: com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.exceptions.MapboxConfigurationException: 
    Using MapView requires calling Mapbox.getInstance(Context context, String accessToken) before inflating or creating the view. The access token parameter is required when using a Mapbox service.
    Please see https://www.mapbox.com/help/create-api-access-token/ to learn how to create one.
    More information in this guide https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-android-sdk/#access-tokens.`
You forgot to provide an accessToken through Mapbox.getInstance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Tobrun for the answer, the problem was not that I missed the accessToken but I mixed activity and fragment layout so the components in one of them should be in the other. However, looking for the accessToken made me realize about other possible ones.

Answer (score 5):

**Set the method:**
 `Mapbox.getInstance(this,getString(R.string.access_token));`
**Before the:**
 *`setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);`*
 If you having this exception change code structure as follows.

i.e:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Mapbox.getInstance(this,getString(R.string.access_token));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(mapboxMap -> mapboxMap.setStyle(
            new Style.Builder().fromUrl(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS)
    ));
}
```